# Deleting maps in a firestore document (cloud functions / Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried many different ways, but nothing works. All I need is to delete a map (within another map called `question_template`) in a `firestore` document, where the name of the map is only known at runtime (given as a parameter `languageName` to the cloud function).

```
const modulesDocument = admin.firestore().collection('quiz').doc('modules');
```

when using template strings, I get this error (I'm using JS btw, not TS):
Property assignment expected.ts(1136)

```
modulesDocument.update({
    `question_template.${languageName}`: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()   
});
```

then I tried this method, which also didn't work:

```
const language = `question_template.${languageName}`;

modulesDocument.update({
    //the previously defined 'const language' doesn't get referenced here, why?
    language: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the contents of a string expression as a key in an object definition, put it in square brackets:

```
modulesDocument.update({
    [language]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
modulesDocument.update({
    [`question_template.${languageName}`]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()   
});
```

or

```
const language = `question_template.${languageName}`;

modulesDocument.update({
    [language]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()   
});
```